# OnCollisionEnter2D works multiple times, how to stop this?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a ball in my demo game that has a bounce rate of 0.6. If the ball lands on a platform, of course it bounces. But the thing is, I actually tried to stick the ball to the platform.

When the ball collides with the surface of the platform, the speed of rigid body 2D becomes 0. But I guess because of the bounce rate, ball jumps a little bit and lands again in 0.02 seconds. Because of this, OnCollisionEnter2D runs for 2 times, which is something I don't want. Here is my code;

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(GameObject other) {
    if(other.GameObject.tag == "platform") {
        //Sets the rigidbody2D velocity as zero vector, angular drag and linear drag as 10f
        game.SetBallVelocity(Vector2.zero, 10f, 10f)
    }
}
```

How can I make OncollisionEnter2D only runs for single time? In another word, let the Ball really stick at the first time?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough information to give you the exact answer but one of those should fix the problem:

1: Changing collision mode on the ball's rigidbody (test both Discrete and Continuous)

2: OnCollisionEnter2D is called before the physics calculations that change the ball's velocity, so use OnCollisionExit2D()

Quick side note, your IDE should have warned you of this but `other.gameobject.CompareTag("platform")` is faster than directly comparing the strings (`other.GameObject.tag == "platform"`)